# Trying to sum key values of an object (basically 14 and 16) using .map() and it gives rather a strange result

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I like to sum the grades[0].grade and grades[1].grade (basically 14+16), the result is 30.

I did the coding using .reduce() method as seen below:

```js
function getSumGrades(grades) {

  return grades.reduce(function(acc, grade) {
    return acc += grade.grade
  }, 0)
}

// Sample usage - do not modify
let grades = [{
    name: "Sam Blue",
    grade: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie Bron",
    grade: 16
  }
];
console.log(getSumGrades(grades));
```

But I like to also practise .map() , so I wanted to code with .map and for some reason it gives [ 14, 30 ] as output.

The code, that gives incorrect output is this one:

```js
function getSumGrades(grades) {
  let sum = 0;
  return grades.map(function(grade) {
    return sum = sum + grade.grade;
  })
}

// Sample usage - do not modify
let grades = [{
    name: "Sam Blue",
    grade: 14
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie Bron",
    grade: 16
  }
];
console.log(getSumGrades(grades));
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is your understanding of what `map` is for?

Comment: @Ry- I read that .map loops through an array and then it can modify the array. So I thought, I can loop through the values and then add. Is it wrong? Would you say, we cannot use .map for summing up values? Can we only use reduce method?

Comment: This is not a good use of `map`. The purpose of `map` is to take an array and produce a new array based on the `return` of the mapping function. If you don't want to produce a new array, you don't want `map`. You're getting 30 as the second element because that's what's returned by the second iteration of the mapping function, because thats what `sum + grade.grade` is at that point.

Comment: What you're doing with your code is creating an array containing the running total of the grades of all the students. This is not likely to be useful or interesting.

Comment: This is actually a function in some languages/libraries (see [`reductions`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reductions)), but it's not what is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the way `.map()` works it's kinda different of what you're thinking, it actually creates a new array and change each value of the array to what you've especified.

So each of the objects of the array will actually act as an accumulator on a normal `reduce()` method, so if you really want to use `.map()`, you can still use the way you're doing but only getting the last item of the array, that will be the sum of all the items of the array.

You can use `console.log(getSumGrades(grades[grades.length-1]));` to get the final value

I don't recommend doing this, but I understand it is for leaning purposes